# (Django) How to apply css?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to apply CSS on my Django project.

CSS path in my `index.html` is right but it doesn't work well.

My `index.html` page show up well in my site,

> --app_index
>   ----index.html
>   ----bootstrap
>   -------css
>   -----------abc.css
>   -----------abc2.css

So, must I modify the URL.py file too?

Comment: Here you find information how to configure static files in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure static files in your Django app. The following links should help guide you in the right direction:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates_static.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

You will set up your `index.html` for example in a template directory that can access your static files (e.g. CSS, javascript, static images, etc.) that are located in your static directory.

In response to your question concerning modification of `urls.py`, the answer is yes. As you will see in the links on configuring static files within your project, you have to add some code to your `urls.py`. An example of this code might look like this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
    )
```

During development Django serves your static files hence the above code, but during production your static files are served via your configured server (e.g. Apache, nginx).